# Grid.Mvc.Ajax - Pagination, sorting and Action Link Issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

After about four days I finally managed to get the grid to play with other controls on the same page...

If I leave out a script it will sort, but paging doesn't work and with the script neither work. Every which way I try to get the Action Link to post back to the controller will not work, so any suggestions will certainly help me retain some sanity :-)

Models

```
Imports Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions


Public Class GridData

Public Property Staff_ID As Integer
Public Property Current_Date As Date
Public Property Grid() As AjaxGrid(Of GridDataRows)

Public Property FilterableGrid() As AjaxGrid(Of GridDataRows)

Public Property GridFilter() As GridFilter

Public Sub New()
    GridFilter = New GridFilter
End Sub

End Class
```

..................................................

```
Public Class GridDataRows
Public Property FirstName() As String
Public Property LastName() As String

Public Property Timesheet_ID() As Integer

Public Property Category_ID() As Integer

Public Property Type_ID() As Integer

Public Property TimeSheet_Hours() As String

Public Property Category_Name() As String

Public Property Type_Name() As String

Public Property Timesheet_Comments() As String

End Class
```

Partial

```html
@Imports GridMvc.Html
@Imports GridMvc.Sorting

@*@ModelType Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid(Of GridData)*@
@ModelType GridData


@Code
    Layout = Nothing
End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/Gridmvc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/ladda-bootstrap/ladda-themeless.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/URI.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc-ext.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/gridmvc.customwidgets.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/ladda.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ladda-bootstrap/spin.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    @*@Html.Grid(Model.Grid).AutoGenerateColumns.Sortable(True).WithPaging(10).Named("TSGrid")*@

        @Html.Grid(Model.Grid).Named("TSGrid").Columns(Function(vCols)
                                                           vCols.Add(Function(x) x.Timesheet_ID).Titled("ID").SetWidth(10).Encoded(False).Sanitized(False).SortInitialDirection(GridSortDirection.Descending)
                                                           vCols.Add(Function(x) x.Category_Name).Titled("Property").SetWidth(10).Encoded(False).Sanitized(False)
                                                           vCols.Add(Function(x) x.Type_Name).Titled("Job Type").SetWidth(10).Encoded(False).Sanitized(False)
                                                           vCols.Add(Function(x) x.TimeSheet_Hours).Titled("Hours").SetWidth(10).Encoded(False).Sanitized(False)
                                                           vCols.Add(Function(x) x.Timesheet_Comments).Titled("Comments").SetWidth(100).Encoded(False).Sanitized(False)
                                                           'vCols.Add().Titled("Edit").Sanitized(False).Encoded(False).RenderValueAs(Function(d) Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditTimesheet", "Calendar", New With {.TimesheetID = d.Timesheet_ID, .[class] = "btn btn-primary", .onClick = "gridRowSelected(2);"})).SetWidth(30)
                                                           vCols.Add().Titled("Edit").Sanitized(False).Encoded(False).RenderValueAs(Function(d) Html.ActionLink("Edit x", Nothing, Nothing, New With {.TimesheetID = d.Timesheet_ID, .[class] = "btn btn-primary", .onClick = "gridRowSelected();"})).SetWidth(30)
                                                       End Function).WithPaging(10).Sortable(True)
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

View

```html
@ModelType GridData

@*@ModelType MaintenanceWeb.MainModels*@

@*@Imports GridMvc.html
@Imports Gridmvc.Sorting*@

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Calendar"
End Code

<style>
    td[data-name="TimeSheet_Hours"] {
        text-align: right;
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
</style>

<div style="height: 25px;"></div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 style="text-align: center" id="calendarHeader"></h3>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Select the date you wish to work with</h2>

<div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @Using (Ajax.BeginForm(Nothing, "Calendar/DateChanged", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST"}, New With {.id = "SelectDateForm"}))
            @<div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="datepicker" onchange="onChangeCalender();"></div>
            
            @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(x) Model.Current_Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", New With {.id = "inputMaintDate", .class = "form-control", .type = "date"})

        </div>
                 


        </div>

        End Using



    </div>

    @*@Html.Partial("_DataGrid", New Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid(IQueryable(Of DateGridModels)), 10, False)*@

    @*@Html.RenderPartial("_DataGrid", Model.Item3)*@ 

@Using (Ajax.BeginForm(Nothing, "Calendar/EditTimesheet", Nothing, New AjaxOptions With {.HttpMethod = "POST"}, New With {.id = "GridForm"}))

       @<div>
            <div id="gridFilters">
                <input type="text" name="date">
                <input type="text" name="search">
                
            </div>
            <div Class="form-group">
                <Button id="LoginButton" Class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><span Class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save</Button>

            </div>

        </div>


@code
    Html.RenderPartial("_DataGrid", Model)
End Code



    End Using
    


   

    

    
   

    @*@Html.Partial("_DataGrid", Model.Item3)*@
   
   
   
    

   </div>​
```

Grid script

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ajaxUrl = '/Calendar/GridPaged';

        pageGrids.TSGrid.ajaxify({
            updateGridAction: ajaxUrl,
            getPagedData: ajaxUrl,
           getData: ajaxUrl
          //  gridFilterForm: $("#gridFilters")
        });
       pageGrids.TSGrid.refreshFullGrid();
    });
```

Grid item selected script

```js
function gridRowSelected() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditTimesheet", "Calendar")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#GridForm').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
            }
        });
    }
     ​
```

Controller

```
  Function Index() As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim vData = ReturnData2()
            Dim vGrid = CType(New AjaxGridFactory().CreateAjaxGrid(vData, 1, False), AjaxGrid(Of GridDataRows))
            Return View(New GridData() With {.Grid = vGrid})
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex)
            Return SystemError()
        End Try

    End Function
```

..................

```
 <HttpGet()>
    Function GridPaged(vPage As Integer) As ActionResult
        Try
            Dim vData = ReturnData2()
            Dim vGrid = CType(New AjaxGridFactory().CreateAjaxGrid(vData, vPage, True), AjaxGrid(Of GridDataRows))

            Return View(New GridData() With {.Grid = vGrid})

        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

..........

```
Private Function ReturnData2() As IQueryable(Of GridDataRows)
        Try
            Dim vList As New List(Of GridDataRows)()
            Using vService As New Service1Client
                strSQL = "SELECT Maintenance_Timesheets.Timesheet_ID, "
                strSQL += "Maintenance_Timesheets.Timesheet_Hours, "
                strSQL += "Maintenance_Timesheets.Timesheet_Comments,  "
                strSQL += "Maintenance_Categories.Category_Name, "
                strSQL += "Maintenance_Types.Type_Name "
                strSQL += "FROM Maintenance_Timesheets "
                strSQL += "JOIN Maintenance_Categories ON Maintenance_Categories.Category_ID = Maintenance_Timesheets.Category_ID "
                strSQL += "JOIN Maintenance_Types ON Maintenance_Types.Type_ID = Maintenance_Timesheets.Type_ID "
                strSQL += "WHERE Staff_ID = 5"
                Using DS As DataSet = vService.ReturnDataSetHAS(strSQL)
                    For Each Row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                        vList.Add(New GridDataRows() With {.Timesheet_ID = Row("Timesheet_ID"), .Category_Name = ReturnText(Row("Category_Name")), .Type_Name = ReturnText(Row("Type_Name")), .TimeSheet_Hours = Format(Row("Timesheet_Hours"), "##0.00"), .Timesheet_Comments = ReturnText(Row("Timesheet_Comments"))})
                    Next
                End Using
            End Using
            Return vList.AsQueryable
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

===================== EDIT UPDATE ========================

Changing the script to :-

```
<script>
function gridRowSelected(SelectItem) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EditTimesheet", "Calendar")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { vID: SelectItem },
        success: function (response) {
        }
    });
    //alert(SelectItem)
}
```

and the grid line to

```
vCols.Add().Titled("Edit").Sanitized(False).Encoded(False).RenderValueAs(Function(d) Html.ActionLink("Edit x", Nothing, Nothing, New With {.TimesheetID = d.Timesheet_ID, .[class] = "btn btn-primary", .onClick = "gridRowSelected(" & d.Timesheet_ID & ");"})).SetWidth(30)
```

and the controller to

```
<HttpPost()>
    Function EditTimesheet(vID As Integer) As ActionResult
        Try
            Return ModalValidation(vID)
        Catch ex As Exception
            EmailError(ex)
            Return SystemError()
        End Try
    End Function
```

It now sends the correct id back to the controller. If I set an alert in the script the Modal pops up with the correct ID, but then closes after the alert is closed. Without the alert you cannot even tell that the modal was raised. I suspect the grid refreshes and causes the modal to close. Getting a little closer... Still have the paging issue though

=====================EDIT UPDATE 2 ===================================

Adding return false prevented the grid from posting back and now everything works apart from paging and sorting

```
vCols.Add().Titled("Edit").Sanitized(False).Encoded(False).RenderValueAs(Function(d) Html.ActionLink("Edit x", Nothing, Nothing, New With {.TimesheetID = d.Timesheet_ID, .[class] = "btn btn-primary", .onClick = "gridRowSelected(" & d.Timesheet_ID & ");return false;"})).SetWidth(30)
```

Comment: Why is your partial a full HTML document?

Comment: Where exactly is the issue? Does the controller action get called when a new page is clicked? Is there a javascript error on the background, is the javascript console clean?

Comment: The controller action is not being called - script is running and shows no errors. At one stage it did fire at the controller, but I have changed so many things I'm not sure what stopped that!

Comment: Paul Abbott - sorry didn't see your comment before. I just clicked to create a partial and accepted the defaults if I remember correctly - I generally develop WPF and have worked with WebForms so still getting used to quite a few concepts in MVC

Comment: I have moved the scripts and stylesheet links to the main view and deleted the html - still the same issues though